# PHP Google Calendar API - Import Event

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have downloaded the google-api-php-client and updated the calendar/sample.php file.
But where should the code to import events go?
into the sample.php file
And what is the redirect url for... or should the code go there?

Thanx
martin

Answer (score 0):

Check the Calendar API sample included with the PHP client library (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php) and put your code instead of

```
$calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
```

which is the line executed after the auth flow is completed.